# Visualizing long list of data

Tags: usability, lists

I have got a list of 50-80 items that I need to be visualized in a useful way. The list is sorted in alphabetic order.

The items will be draggable to a graph on its right, like so:

[image]

I’m thinking there should be a search field as well to make it easier for the user to find what he/she is looking for, but still, a plain list of 80 items it not very to use. Unfortunately there is no way to categorize or group the items.

Comment: What is a number for items you expect to be selected simultaneously?

Comment: Are you consider your UI to be used with tablets (touch input)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of including a search to filter the list of items is a good one. Below is an example taken from Google Analytics. The tooltip is a nice touch in the event your users need help setting up the report.

You will likely want to indicate (by color or other indication) which items have already been selected.

[image: example field selector]

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following :

- Since you cannot create meaningful categories, you can create arbitrary categories i.e. alphanumeric : A-D, E-K etc.
- Display the 5 most frequently used in a separate list
- The search you are thinking is a very good idea